# Repeat an action after a delay

Tags: swift

I would like to repeat a sequence of actions, each repetition taking place **after** a waiting time.

I tried this:

`action1rep` = number of repetitions
`action1reptime` = delay

```swift
for i in 1...action1rep {           
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(action1reptime)) {
        launch(action: action1a)
        launch(action: action1b)
        launch(action: action1c)
        launch(action: action1d)
    }
}
```

But the actions are all repeated at the same time after the same delay because `for i in [...]...[...]` does not wait for the actions it contains to be completed before repeat...

Comment: Replace `.seconds(action1reptime)` with `.seconds(action1reptime * i)`